# Postgres: Ranking difference between a column where two columns are the same

Tags: sql, postgresql

Right now I have a table like the following:

```
 pkey ckey         ckey          1 < < 10
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| id | product_id | retrived_at | category_id | price |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 1  | python     | 2023-01-01  | 1           | 1000  |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 2  | cpp        | 2023-01-01  | 1           | 1500  |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 3  | python     | 2023-01-02  | 1           | 2200  |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 4  | cpp        | 2023-01-02  | 1           | 2100  |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 5  | python     | 2023-01-02  | 2           | 2700  |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 6  | cpp        | 2023-01-02  | 2           | 3000  |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

where there is a composite key on `product_id` and `retrived_at`, and the primary key on `id`, but for distiguishing purposes. There's only around 10 `category_id` variations, ranging from 1~10.

What I want is a rank of the difference between `price` where `product_id` are the same, with `retrieved_at` and `category_id` supplied as a `WHERE` clause.

So, if I wanted to rank the difference in `price` between '2023-01-01' and '2023-01-02', and want a `category_id = 1` , I'd get something like this:

```
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| product_id | category_id | price_difference |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| python     | 1           | 1200             |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| cpp        | 1           | 600             |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
```

I have 300 million rows in the table right now, is there a way to do this quickly? I have ~500K rows for each `retrived_at` value. I only need to get the top ~20

Comment: Also, what should be returned in your example if `category_id = 2`?

Comment: @markalex That was a typo, fixed. category_id should be identical. I've omitted category_id = 2, since I wanted to demonstrate that it sohuld be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want straight difference between price at the end date and price at start date:

```sql
with beg_price as(
  select product_id, price
  from mytable
  where category_id = :p_category
  and retrived_at = :p_beginning
),
end_price as(
  select product_id, price
  from mytable
  where category_id = :p_category
  and retrived_at = :p_end
) 
select b.product_id, e.price - b.price
from beg_price b
join end_price e on b.product_id = e.product_id
```

And if you want range between minimum and maximum price in specified time range, you can do it even simpler using `min` and `max` functions and group by:

```sql
SELECT  product_id, category_id,
        max(price) max_price, min(price) min_price,
        max(price) - min(price) price_range
FROM mytable   
where category_id = :p_category
  and retrived_at BETWEEN :p_beginning and :p_end
GROUP BY product_id, category_id
```